how to fix warning AD_ID permission in cordova app with cordova-plugin-firebasex?
I use this plugin for firebase:
https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex
When I publish I have this warning on play console:
Advertising IDs of applications that target Android 13 (API 33) without AD_ID authorization will be reset. This may impact your use in the areas of advertising and analytics
I have declared in the config.xml file:
<config-file parent="/manifest" target="AndroidManifest.xml" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />
        </config-file>

Should libraries like this be updated?
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads
com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics

Thanks for your help.
